# Any idea why my Lazyload is not working?

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

Anyone have any idea why my lazy load does not seem to be working?

I copied exactly from the lazy load page even using their images as a test, they just load in normal rather than fade...?

[lazy link example](http://jezthompson.co.uk/view/test.html)

I then put a no conflict script in as i have drop down as well, nothing there either which fixed it...

Just loosely fades in first the rest of the images do nothing :(

Very odd..

Answer (score 2):

Taken another look:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(function() {           // <-- what's this doing here?
    jQuery("img").lazyload({
        placeholder: "/images/blank.gif",
        effect: "fadeIn",
        failurelimit: 1,
        threshold: -20
    });
  });
});
```

You're setting an onload event in your onload handler, that's odd. Remove it and it may work

Comment: Thanks for you help, even with that out it still doesn't work :(

My original one has this and that didn't work either...


$(function() {          
          $("img").lazyload({
          placeholder : "/images/blank.gif",
                      effect      : "fadeIn",
                      failurelimit : 1,
                      threshold: -20
          });
      });  


Its confusing me..

Comment: I've got it to work locally but doesn't work once online :(

Tried a few domains as well.

Very strange..

http://snipt.org/loolp/

Comment: @Jezthump: The problem can be that jQuery loads the images through Ajax, which doesn't work if you have your images on another domain, due to the same origin policy. To fix this you might need to move you images to the same domain

Comment: Thanks Harmen but still nothing...

Doesn't work online whatever i do here is my latest effort 

http://studioview.co.uk/jeztest/ :(

Comment: @Jezthomp: your grey.gif image is missing, maybe that's it? — According to Chrome's Developer Tools

Comment: Thanks again Harmen, it seems like it didn't like not having any space between the images.

Wouldn't let me  just have the images, needed to have a break or have the in a list.

Still the Safari problem but managed to get it working. :)

Answer (score 2):

LazyLoad doesn't work anymore...

Modern browser download images before the dom loaded event occours.

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

... the author says...

Lazy Load is currently not usable. It does not work with the latest browsers as expected. I have currently no time updating the code myself. Patches are always welcome. If you find a solution just fork and send a pull request. Thanks!

Comment: It is the part of automatically removing image src which does not work anymore. Version 1.5 released Dec 23, 2009 provided alternative where you must alter HTML and store image url in `original` attribute. I renamed it recently to `data-original`to be HTML5 friendly. I also updated to [documentation](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) which better explains how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It may also worth it to check out this plugin called [JAIL](http://www.sebarmeli.com/projects/jail) lazy loads images